# GtkVBox inside GtkFixed panel

Tags: c, user-interface, gtk

I'm trying to develop a GTK desktop application.

I want to display an image and make some clickable areas on the image. For this reason, I'm using GtkFixed container to put the image and clickable areas(GtkEventBox is used for areas). After the user clicks on a GtkEventBox, I want to display a box in the clicked area. For this reason, I have thought to use GtkVBox to make a box to display.

The problem is that GtkVBox is not visible inside a GtkFixed container parent. So I am stuck at that point. Is it possible to use GtkVBox inside GtkFixed? If not, what is the proper method of doing this job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, it was a mistake that I used `gtk_widget_show` to make container visible instead of `gtk_widget_show_all`. It works now